# running rspec spec/ doesn't result in proper output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm doing the Ruby On Rails 3 Tutorial (Learn Rails By Example) by Michael Hartl book.

I'm on chapter 3, and my output isn't what Michael has in the book. Can someone help?

```
admin@new-host:~/Desktop/sample_app$ rspec spec/
Exception encountered: #<NameError: uninitialized constant PagesController>
backtrace:
/Users/admin/Desktop/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
```

**spec_helper.rb:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  unless defined?(Rails)
    require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
  end

  require 'rspec/rails'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear

  end


end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

**based off of Ismael's advice. I did this and got the following output:**

```
admin@new-host:~/Desktop/sample_app$ rspec --pattern spec/*_spec.rb
Exception encountered: #<NameError: uninitialized constant PagesController>
backtrace:
/Users/admin/Desktop/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'

admin@new-host:~/Desktop/sample_app$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `load': /Users/admin/Desktop/sample_app/.autotest:3: unterminated string meets end of file (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `block in initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:314:in `each'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:314:in `initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/autotest/rspec2.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-rails-2.12.0/lib/autotest/rails_rspec2.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:244:in `new'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:244:in `run'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/bin/autotest:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/autotest:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace code in spec_helper with this code: https://raw.github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/master/spec/spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be in the project directory.

If still doesn't work try running this way instead:

```
rspec --pattern spec/*_spec.rb
```

Comment: Hey Ismael. I tried your advice and posted the output I got above.

Comment: Didn't `rspec spec/` worked? Maybe you need the `bundle exec`, or you are missing the `require 'rspec_helper'` in your test

Comment: also how is the controller named PageController or PagesController?

Comment: Hey Ismael. When doing "rspec spec/", I get "Exception encountered: #<NameError: uninitialized constant PagesController..." when you say I need the bundle exec what do you mean? I'm adding in the require 'rspec_helper' into my .autotest file and seeing if that changes things.

Comment: just tried 'rspec spec/' again with the new addition to the .autotest file and still got the same error.

Comment: Ok, so you where just in the wrong directory :) That error actually has nothing to do with problems in your specs. I think you might have your controller named PageController instead of PagesController. Can you confirm that please?

Comment: Or maybe you even have created it, wich is normal, since you are doing the test and then you write the actual code. No?

Comment: I looked around and I saw that I have a pages_controller.rb with class PagesController ... I also have a pages_helper.rb, pages_controller_spec.rb. I used the rails generate command in terminal to make the pages controller. Now I'm just trying to run the tests which just check whether the pages exist or not. This is my first time doing tdd. I'm a rails noob.

Comment: Hm, so if you have that ok, what might be happening is that the rails app is not beeing loaded. That's maybe because you are using Spork. I've never used it but I think you first need to run `spork`, and in a different terminal session then you can run rspec. You are using too much stuff if you are new to rails. Probably using the base stuff should be better for you.

Comment: Hey Ismael thanks so much for staying through this with me. 

Apparently since I was using updated versions of gems that my tutorial wasn't using. I had to update my spec_helper.rb file to reflect the new gems.

I got the code here: https://raw.github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/master/spec/spec_helper.rb